# Issue with Angular UI bootstrap static tab default selection

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

i am facing an issue with angular bootstrap ui static tabs default selection.

I have around seven tab like this in a model popup. I want to set default tab based on value. i have done something like this

```
<uib-tab select="getCurrentTab('basic')" active="active.two"  heading="Basic">
```

in script

```
 $scope.active={
   one:false,
  two: true
 }
```

Issue is it always selects the first tab,irrespective of the scope
field

Comment: Sorry, with the above code it works

Answer (score 0):

ng-class="{active: active.two}"

Set the active class using ng-class
This may help you.